# Ethernet switching architecture

Tags: ethernet, architecture

I'm currently designing the electronics for the new version of our robots.

On the current version, all the Ethernet switching is done with off the shelf switches/devices (there is just a single Ethernet connection to the embedded computer (Jetson)).

On the new version, I need far more Ethernet connections, with several devices directly integrated on the PCB. I would therefore like to integrate everything onto the PCB in order to reduce the cabling (and the associated failures).

I would like some advice about the best architecture.

**Current architecture:**
[image: current architecture]
Currently, we use a redundant media converter, taking 2 fiber connections (only one used at a time, the second is just a backup with automatic switchover) coming from the control station, and converting them to a single 1 Gbps twisted pair interface.

We then connect this 1 Gbps ethernet cable to a first 5 port PoE switch (each port 1 Gbps), which in turn is connected to a second switch (non PoE, 5 1 Gbps ports).

Both switches are of the shelf devices, and the only thing on PCB is the embedded computer (a Jetson SoM).

Note that all connections are for 1Gbps, but the circuit is full of bottle-necks

**New architecture:**
[image: new architecture]
This time, I want everything on the PCB (as I added several ethernet devices on PCBs, connectors will often bundle with other wires (supplies and other signals), some will get PoE, ...).

Redundant fiber:

I still need redundant fiber, and I would like to increase the "nominal" bandwidth to 10 Gbps (I'm OK with only 5 Gbps in case one fiber fails, so traffic sharing between two 5 Gbps links is an option)

I need some massive switching (at least 10 Gbps total traffic):

- 10 Gbps uplink (to control station)
- 2.5 Gbps to embedded computer
- 4  1 Gbps connections
- 13 100 Mbps connections

Note that nearly all traffic will be to or from either the control station or the embedded computer (traffic between devices might happen, but <<10 Mbps).

A about 2/3 of the 1 Gbps/100 Mbps ports will provide PoE to the devices (for the 100 Mbps devices on the data pair).

So my core question is how best to architecture all this ethernet circuits.

More particularly:

1. Should I look into redundant fiber or traffic sharing?
2. Should the redundancy/traffic sharing happen in a dedicated component, or should this functionality go into the switch?
3. Is it easier to use one huge switch (IC), which as far as I found out so far would then lack the PHYs, so I have to add them separately, or to use several smaller switches with integrated PHYs?
4. Should the PoE injection be done by separated ICs, or should I try to find it bundled with the PHY? (or even bundled switch+PHY+PoE injector?)

PS: In my opinion, it's easier to answer this as a single big question than separating it into several smaller ones (which would lack of context). But if you think otherwise, I'm happy to split this question.

NB: I'm not looking for suggestions of specific ICs, but for how I should split the functionalities between several (generic) ICs.

EDIT :
To reply to @Kuba hasn't forgotten Monica 's answer :

- I confirm, the cost of components don't matter much (development time and reliability matter more)
- volume is low enough that if one part is really critical and hard to replace, we can probably buy enough stock to be sure to have more than needed for the whole lifetime of the product (at least until the next major revision)
- for the PoE devices, most are external to the electronics enclosure, and some are provided by our customers (sometimes without integration on our side), and there is always a risk of the customer switching devices. So all PoE output need a form or another of over-current protection (with or without negociation).
- For the reliability, we only had one cable failing (not sure if it was an old one or the better ones we buy know), and a few temporary failures due to bad wiring at mounting or after maintenance (quickly detected by testing and relatively easy to correct, but still some non negligible time lost). The main issue is that we have far to many cables (and most of the external connectors are connected to several different PCBs), so each intervention is a big pain (and high risk of human error). As all 100Mbps signals come with 4 other wires, I want to have a unique connector.
- Globally, space is at a premium, and can't reasonably be extended, so adding extra of the shelf components is limited (in the current design, we already had trouble adding the second Ethernet switch when we needed it)
- What might be an option (even if I have never seen one) would be PCB mountable switches (something like an arduino shield, with a connector adapted for at least the 100Mbps ethernet, the 1Gbps Ethernet could be wired directly without passing through the PCB

Comment: How are you planning that redundancy? Active/passive on L2 (like static LAG)? Virtual MAC? Virtual IP? Just redundancy is always simpler than balancing load, so it's what you require. How long are you planning to build this rig? Life expectancy of the required parts should be a serious consideration. Or make this as modular as possible so you can redesign every 1-2 years. Volume?

Comment: For the redundancy, it is still open (currently we use media converters at each end that convert ethernet to 2 fibers (one active, one backup)). The trade of is lad balancing at 5 Gbps vs redundancy at 10Gbps. But my gut feeling is that redundancy will be easier.
I expect that we build those PCBs for about 5 years at most (before needing a new PCB due to obsolescence of parts and changing requirements). Volume : I would guess in the 40-200 range over the lifetime of this design, in batches of about 10-20 (excepted first prototypes).

Comment: With just 40-200 pieces, the ROI for an integrated 10G switch including firmware is very unlikely unless you've got a really sweet margin. Have you really calculated the whole project, including support?

Comment: The goal is not to develop a switch, but a whole control board for the robot doing a lot of other things (I would guess the ethernet part will be at most 1/5th of the number of components). And the whole control board will not be more than a few percents of the material costs of the robot. The most critical thing is development time. For the switch, I was thinking that I could find a switching IC with no firmware to be written (just some limited configuration done in a couple of weeks): am I to optimistic about this? NB: I don't need anything fancy, just some basic point to point communication

Answer (score 2):

> Is it easier to use one huge switch (IC), which as far as I found out so far would then lack the PHYs, so I have to add them separately, or to use several smaller switches with integrated PHYs?

It's really hard to say. Yours is a low-volume, high-engineering-cost product, so choose whatever you feel will cost less time and aggravation to design-in. The price of the chip matters not in the cost to the company. You'd need truly egregiously priced chips to have to worry about that.

> Should the PoE injection be done by separated ICs, or should I try to find it bundled with the PHY? (or even bundled switch+PHY+PoE injector?)

Wide-range PoE PSE needs a power ASIC and support from the MAC. I'm sure someone could integrate it all into one package, so if you can find it and it's easy to apply - why not. But do mind getting yourself cornered availability-wise. It's much easier to redesign smaller chunks of functionality.

Since you are working with a closed system, it's probably acceptable to hardwire a protected power sources onto some of the Ethernet lines, if the downstream devices can use that. Loads light enough not to involve link layer in power negotiation will work just fine that way. So you only need load protection using general-purpose chips, but nothing PoE-specific other than the magnetics.

> This time, I want everything on the PCB

If you don't have experience doing board-level design for gigabit ethernet, it may not be very worthwhile of your effort. Why would the single PCB you design be more reliable than devices from manufacturers with experience in the field of industrial networking? Even just having the prototypes of that high-density PCB assembled will cost quite a bit of money. And you will likely need at least one or two respins if you haven't done this before. It's hard to add bodge wires to high speed interconnects, unless the bodges are needed in slow parts of the circuit.

> in order to reduce the cabling (and the associated failures)

Something is seems wrong if internal cabling is the source of failures. It generally is "plug stuff in and forget about it". I'd stop right there and re-evaluate what's going on, what the actual documented failure rates are (vs. perceived rates), and so on.

Industrial ethernet can be had with high-reliability, vibration-resistant connectors, and so on. Anecdotally speaking, I've had industrial ethernet deployed inside machine cabinets and the cabling was rock solid, since it was certified for the environment we put it in, with the manufacturer standing behind their product. The only interconnect failures we had were from point-to-point "PLC-style" wiring.

It sounds a bit like your project may end up replacing off-the-shelf industrial patch cables with a bunch of expensive custom engineering.

---

There definitely is not a single right answer to your conundrum. Start with hard data and some estimates of how much field failures cost. Review existing design for use of cables and connectors outside of intended environments. Are you buying patch cords from a trusted cable manufacturer (say L-Com), or are they generic stuff?

Your general view of this project is IMHO questionable. Not necessarily wrong, just that there's way too little information you have provided (and can provide without violating corporate policy) to come up with solid guidance. You may wish to hire a consultant or a VAR vendor with experience in gigabit industrial ethernet to go over this stuff.